# Vue and vue-router nested view links having router-link in JSON format

Tags: vue.js, nested, vue-router

Nested views, in vue-router, are greats!

I have a few of links point to them just like:

```
<router-link :to="'/club/'+team.id_team+'/players'">Players</router-link>
```

If you know vue-router you will see here the path items:

- "club" is the router path, his *name* in the router is "team";
- team.id_team is the params *teamId*
- "players" is the children path (which has the same name: "players"

It works nice but I prefer to write my code in :to tag as JSON data but I'm not able using it with nested view.

[Nested view doc](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html)

This is the form I like to use:

```
:to="{name:'team',params: {teamId:team.serie_id}}"
```

And this is the router:

```
{ path: '/club/:teamId',

    name:'team',

    component: team,

    children :[

        {
            name:'players',
            path: 'players',
            component: teamPlayers,
        },

        {
            name:'staff',
            path: 'staff',
            component: teamStaff,
            params: true,
        },

        {
            name:'table',
            path: 'table',
            component: teamTable,
            params: true,
        }

    ]},
```

How to update this last line to use the nested view?

Comment: did you try :to="{path:'club/'+team.id_team , name:'team',params: {teamId:team.serie_id}}"

Comment: Thanks @ishaym the :to="{name:'team',params: {teamId:team.serie_id}}" works but I need to add the children name ("players") here. I have done some tests but it dosn't work

Comment: Can you post your router file, all depends how you've set up your nested routes. might as simple as changing the name from `team` to `players` in your router link

Comment: @Rich thanks for your help. I've just updated my post showing the router about team page

Comment: Have you tried `:to="{ name: 'players', params: { teamId: team.serie_id } }"`?

Comment: yes I do. But my question is different lol. I need to play with children... I would like to use same JSON format but to  open child view ( ie. team/1/staff). If you see my question I wrote I already do this but I'd like to use JSON in :to.

Comment: Hmm I understand what you mean... I'm trying it I think to have a conflict in my whole router. Let me check...

Comment: Yes! So Sorry...I had a router conflict! And children's names were not unique!  THANKS for help!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using a children routes, you need to make sure you have a nested `<router-view />` on your parent component, in your case that's `team`.

Your team template should look something like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <router-link :to="{
            name: 'players',
            params: { teamId: 1 }
        }">Players</router-link>

        <router-view />
    </div>
</teamplate>
```

When players is clicked, it will then be loaded within the nested `<router-view />`

Comment: I've mocked up a basic [copepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ewVmXe?editors=1011) if you watch the console, i'm logging the route, you can see the name changes between team and players

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time! I was using not unique names in children... now it works perfectly!! thanks again :)